# How do I get the context Menu "oncreate" Event

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I write a Chrome extension. This extension should add items to the Chrome context menü if a text is selected. This should happen dynamically everytime the contextmenu is opened.

As on this image:

[image: http://imgur.com/pJ5Fp]

## The Problem:

I can't find any event that is triggered (and works) if the contextmenu opens. The following code sample doesn't work.

> `window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(){
>                    DynamicMenu.generateMenu(window.getSelection());
>           });`

It's also impossible to trigger the adding of dynamic items from the "test" item:

> `chrome.contextMenus.create(
>   {
>   "title": "test", 
>   "contexts" :["selection"],
>   "onclick" : DynamicMenu.generateMenu
>   });`

Thanks for your help!

**Update** (how it now works):

Manifest:

```
...
     "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
          "js": ["document_event.js"],
          "run_at" : "document_idle"
        }
      ],
...
```

document_event.js:

```
  window.addEventListener('mousedown',  function(e) { 
        var rightclick; 
        if (!e) var e = window.event; 
        if (e.which) rightclick = (e.which == 3); 
        else if (e.button) rightclick = (e.button == 2); 
        if(rightclick){
            var searchText = window.getSelection().toString();
            chrome.extension.sendRequest({search: searchText}, function(response) {
                ...
            });
        }
    });
```

content.js

```
...
    chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
              function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
                var a = request.search;
                            ...
                sendResponse({}); 
            });
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE:  contextMenu `onCreate` Event

---

It's less of an official event per se, as it is a simple async callback built into the chrome.extension.create() method signature:

[**`integer|string`**] `chrome.contextMenus.create(`**`object`**`createProps,`**`function`** `cb)`

**Parameters:**

1. *REQUIRED*: an **object** representing optional `createProperties`.  All the properties are *optional*, but, the `createProperties` object itself is *required* as the first parameter to the `create()` method.  So, if you don't want to use an **custom options/properties**, simply supply an empty object `{}`
2. *OPTIONAL*: a **function** which it callbacks when the `create()` method **completes**.

**Return Value:**

1. Either:

   - an auto-generated **integer** if you do not provide an `id` property in the `createProperties` object parameter when calling the method.
   - a **string** representing the `generatedId` of the context menu/menu item.  A string is only returned if you supplied one in the `createProperties` object parameter when you called the `create()` method, and **if** successfully created, the **string** you supplied will be the **EXACT VALUE** that is returned.

The latest docs for the chrome.contextMenus.create API are here:

- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#create

---

.

#### In your case/example, you should modify your code like so:

```
var gId;  //the id that is generated if the menu is created successfully
gId = chrome.contextMenus.create(
  {//start createProperties
  "title": "test", 
  "contexts" :["selection"],
  "onclick" : DynamicMenu.generateMenu
  },//end createProperties
  function cmItmCreated_handler(){  //your callback (create event, if you will)
    if (typeof chrome.runtime.lastError === "undefined") {
      console.log("context menu/item created.  'gId' var contains generated id");
    }
    else {
      console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    }
  }//end function cmItmCreated_handler()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried tracking the right click event? The chrome extension [context menu](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html#apiReference) APIs mostly deal with clicks on the new context menu items.

Comment: How do you me mean the right click event?
Should I capture
`window.addEventListener('mousedown', doSomething);
function doSomething(e) {
     var rightclick;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.which) rightclick = (e.which == 3);
    else if (e.button) rightclick = (e.button == 2);
    if(rightclick)DynamicMenu.generateMenu(window.getSelection());
}`
I'll check that out! Or did you mean something else?